# Can't install Teamviewer (version 11 or 12) because of dependencies, help

Tags: software-installation

I need to have Teamviewer in  my laptop but I can't install it because of too many dependencies. I didn't have that problem with Freya in my other laptop. Any solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214746/how-to-run-apt-get-install-to-install-all-dependencies)

Basically you'll run

```
sudo apt install -f
```

to install dependencies